# Best method to utilize enum with Angular / Mongoose / Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, enums

What is the best method to fetch values from MongoDB and display their corresponding values with AngularJS? It's pretty darn simple with Jade but gets messy with Angular.

Here is the data flow:

- an array of items are fetched from the MongoDB, containing couple
  string fields that are enum keys
- enum values are stored in a js as objects, such as:

  ```
  enum = {types: {"type1" : "apple", "type2": "orange"}}
  ```
- with jade, using express and node, a global enum function is called with

  ```
  #{getEnum("types", fruit.fruittype)}
  ```

  where fruittype is "type1" for this fruit.

But when we try to follow a similar method with angular things get complicated with the backend access. What might be the best solution to print the correspondences in such a case? An angular factory object? A map-reduce of some sorts on the set fetched?

P.S. At the moment I am directly forEach'ing the list, extracting the values from the function, it works but I need to create a different field on the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tip: You cannot call backend services from Html Templates. Reason: completion of an angular XHR results in a rootScope.$apply which will trigger a refresh of the html interpolation which will again trigger the xhr in an infinite loop.

Solution: 
Setup the enums you need from the controllers *constructor* using a backend service. And then bind to the data using normal angular binding.

For backend services I recommend using Angular Services, which are basically just TypeScript classes as singletons : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yis8m3BdnEM&hd=1